# On Android MainDisplayInfoChanged event doesn't trigger on RequestedOrientation

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to implement a mediaplayer in Xamarin.Forms, and to make a full screen function I've added a button which toggles the device between landscape and portrait. This works fine, but for some reason my android device doesn't trigger the DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfoChanged event until I actually flip the phone to match the new orientation.

So the app DOES change orientation, but doesn't fire the event until I physically flip my phone. This is happening on a physical device.

On iOS this works fine, so I'm a little confused.

My shared code on the video player page:

```
private void VideoControlView_ToggleFullScreen(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_isFullScreen)
        DependencyService.Get<IOrientationService>().SetOrientationToPortrait();
    else
        DependencyService.Get<IOrientationService>().SetOrientationToLandscape();
}

private async void DeviceDisplay_MainDisplayInfoChanged(object sender, DisplayInfoChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (AutoRotateDisabled)
        return;

    await DisplayVideoFullScreen(e.DisplayInfo.Orientation == DisplayOrientation.Landscape);
}
```

And my service to change the orientation for android:

```
public class OrientationService : IOrientationService
{
    public void SetOrientationToLandscape()
    {
        ((Activity)Forms.Context).RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape;
    }

    public void SetOrientationToPortrait()
    {
        ((Activity)Forms.Context).RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;       
    }
}
```

And for iOS just in case:

```
public class OrientationService : IOrientationService
    {
        private const string ORIENTATION_KEY = "orientation";

        public void SetOrientationToLandscape()
        {
            SetOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight);
        }

        public void SetOrientationToPortrait()
        {
            SetOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait);
        }

        public void SetOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation orientation)
        {
            UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SetValueForKey(new NSNumber((int)orientation), new NSString(ORIENTATION_KEY));
        }
    }
```

To recap:
When I trigger my ToggleFullScreen event, my android device corrently enters landscape mode, but it does NOT trigger MainDisplayInfoChanged.
I have tested this on two different physical android devices with the same issue.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It seems there are an issue on android simulator, you could post an issue here https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues

Comment: To clarify, I am testing this on a physical android device (and have tried two different)

Comment: I've tried it on simulator and did not work very well.